# SoapUI seems to be incorrectly saying these restrictions are invalid. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: wsdl, xsd, soapui

I have the following in my XML Schema:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="DECIMAL_TYPE">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="-100000"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="100000"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="ANGLE_VALUE_TYPE">
    <xsd:restriction base="DECIMAL_TYPE">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="360"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="ANGLE_TYPE">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
         <xsd:extension base="ANGLE_VALUE_TYPE">
              <xsd:attribute name="UNITS" type="xsd:string" fixed="degrees"/>
         </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="SPECIAL_ANGLE_TYPE">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
         <xsd:restriction base="ANGLE_TYPE">
              <xsd:maxInclusive value="90" /> <!-- The source of the problem -->
         </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This schema is used in a WSDL that I'm using as the basis for a new SoapUI project. However, when I try to import the project, SoapUI gives this error:

> - There was something wrong with the WSDL you are trying to import:
>
>   - Source: null
>   - Error: Must be less than or equal to previous maxInclusive

If I change the '90' in the problem line to be equal to '360', the same error appears.

If I remove the line with the comment ("The source of the problem") then SoapUI imports the WSDL just fine. The schema successfully validates in Eclipse, and WSDL2Java runs fine on it.

What, if anything, is wrong with my schema, and what do I need to do to import this to SoapUI? Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a sample WSDL that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your problem is related to the fact that ANGLE_TYPE names ANGLE_BASE_TYPE as its base type, but your schema fragment has no declaration for such a type.

When I change the declaration to name ANGLE_VALUE_TYPE, both Saxon and Xerces tell me the schema document is valid, and once augmented with some element declarations it seems to behave as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately that's not it. The `ANGLE_BASE_TYPE` was a typo in my question. I've edited to reflect the actual XML.